# Joomla 3.x Protostar - How to resize mult-select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I am using the protostar template and I need to enable the multi-select dropdowns to be resized by the user (similar to textarea). I am using Fabrik - but I believe this is not something I need to do in fabrik - I think it needs to be done in the protostar template css/js.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello! Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at StackExchange. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you ask your question there. joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: have you tried adding some css like *width:100px* ?